# Github issues integration with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I already have Github set up in Android studio.
I can commit, push and everything else.
What I can't figure out is how do create and manage Github issues with Android studio?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Thank you for correcting my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do.

### Integrate Github (not git) server

- Tools -> Tasks & Contexts -> Configure Servers
- Add a github server (not gitlab) an set your repo stuff there

### Work on issues

Once done, you can create, work on, close issues

- Tools -> Tasks & Contexts -> Switch task (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on windows)

You can open, mark as resolved, create branch for the issue.
If you want it closed you can include `closes #123` in your commit message which will close it (this doesn't have to be from within android studio, github recognizes it as a command).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you've got set up in Android Studio is Git, not GitHub. Git is the version control system, GitHub just hosts the repositories and essentially pretties it up for you. Issues aren't in any way actually associated with your git repository, except through GitHub and as a result, what you're trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: It seems to be possible, check my answer.